# writing a python dictionary to a text file python

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x, dictionary

im storing a text file to a python dictionary, making changes to the text file.

The issue im facing is with updating the dictionary contents to the text file.

Code to read text file:

```
    with open ('wvtc_data.txt','r')as x:
      for line in x:
            line = line.rstrip ('\n')
            items = line.split (':')
            key,value = items[0], items[1:]
            main_dic[key] = value
            choice=0
            while choice != QUIT:
                  choice = get_menu_choice()
                  if choice==DISPLAY:
                      display(main_dic)
                  elif choice==CHANGE:
                      change(main_dic)
                  elif choice== REMOVE:
                      remove (main_dic)
                  elif choice==WRITE:
                      write(main_dic)
```

I need the write function (the last one)to update the text file with the changes made to the dictionary 
Please help!

Comment: The easiest way would be to simply close the file once you've read the data, and completely overwrite it in your write method. Updating part of a file is rather complex in all but some special cases.

Comment: Just answered exactly the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19295788/989121

Comment: @thg435 how is that 'exactly the same question'? Your answer deals with writing JSON, that's probably not what OP wants...

Comment: I do need to overwrite it completely.

Comment: And i dont want to change the format of the entries either it just needs to copy the dictionary back to the text file as it is..

Comment: Then simply open the file for writing and write the data in whatever format you need. You can't have the file open for reading at the same time though, so you'll need to rearrange your code a bit, e.g. create a list of the file's lines first and then iterate over the list.

Comment: @l4mpi: this is exactly the same question, and my answer applies here literally. json is how you serialize stuff in python.

Comment: @thg435 it's quite obvious by OPs input file isn't in JSON format, and he probably wants to write the same format as well (as you've demonstrated in your answer here, although you should probably `join` the value with `:`). The question you linked deals with serialization in general, where JSON is one of many possible options. That's certainly not the same question.

Comment: @l4mpi: I honestly don't care what OP "wants". They're obviously making their first steps in python and programming, and it's a waaaaay more helpful for them and other beginners to show how we developers handle the stuff, rather than to support their naive technical decisions (although I helped them with that too).

Comment: @thg435 The problem with that is that you assume the file format is like this because of a decision OP made, and you don't have sufficient evidence for this assumption. It's just as likely that he has to deal with a specific file format that can't be changed, e.g. because it is read by other third-party programs. And even if he chose this as a method of serialization, you can't just assume that JSON would be the best option, maybe CSV, sqlite or something else would be better in his case. Feel free to suggest alternatives or request clarification from OP, but don't make baseless assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep your existing format, for whatever reason, then try this:

```
with open ('wvtc_data.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for p in main_dic.items():
        fp.write("%s:%s\n" % p)
```

Note that this doesn't preserve the order of keys. Also, in most cases it's much better to use standard formats for serialization.